# Aligning of elements\

Tags: html, css

Каким образом можно расположить элементы (текст, заголовок и картинку) как на изображений

[image]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.box{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
  gap:10px;
  width: 300px;
}
.item{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.item:nth-child(2),
.item:nth-child(4){
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item">картинка</div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item">текст</div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item">стрелка</div>
  <div class="item">текст</div>
</div>
```

Comment: bootstrap подключать?

Comment: @AibarTolegenov это уже по вкусу. а так пример на чистом css